# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError When run Flink table-api program on cluster

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to run my Flink table-api program on local cluster, where I get this error but not in my IDE where it works normally, I tried to make the dependencies scope provided/ compile with no difference.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment, but class was expected
```

I am using Flink 1.8.0

Anyone can help me here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using a consistent version in your dependencies and cluster? Exceptions like this usually indicate mixing of different Flink versions.

Comment: right indeed, I tried to run it on 1.9.0 cluster and 1.8.3 but it failed on both, I turned my dependencies to 1.8.3 like the cluster, it worked. thanks for the help.